# Is there a way to make conditional input fields in Craft CMS?

Tags: craft3, field, conditional

I'd like to use conditional fields in my CMS instance. I found an old plugin called [Reasons](https://github.com/mmikkel/Reasons-Craft). I'm not sure it's compatible with Craft 3, so I'm looking for a workaround.

Answer (score 3):

For what it's worth, it's [coming in Craft 4](https://craftcms.com/blog/craft-4-craft-cloud-announced). The author of the Reasons plugin has [specifically said](https://github.com/mmikkel/Reasons-Craft/wiki/Statement-on-Reasons-2,-Matrix-and-Craft-3) he won't port it to Craft 3, as this will be part of core in the next release.

Comment: Thanks, so let's hope in Craft 4 :)

Answer (score 2):

I really miss the Reasons plugin and am disappointed the makers of Craft didn't roll it in to Craft 3.

Not quite what you're looking for, but you could try using the Control Panel CSS and Control Panel JS to add lightswitches that show/hide specific fields. You could start with the field hidden, and require a click on the lightswitch to show it.

It's a bit of a hack, but can work well.